# In Python, what is the best way/data structure to rollup account codes or any other type of data that is linked to one another?

Tags: python

52.13.03.014.10

Above I have an account code that needs to be rolled up as such:

52

52.13

52.13.03

52.13.03.014

52.13.03.014.10

Other than string manipulation, how can I do this roll up while starting with the account code: 52.13.03.014.10 ?

I start with the full account code and would like to insert the roll up into excel like this:
[Excel Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99N8B.png)

Comment: It's a string.  You need to manipulate it.  Right?  ;)  `s.split('.')` and then put the pieces back together one at a time.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes its a string but I wonder if there's any other way to do it other than with string manipulation. The answer below seems like the best

Comment: The answer below is doing exactly what I said.  It is manipulating strings.  I think you're looking for magic that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate):

```
s = '52.13.03.014.10'

from itertools import accumulate

out = list(accumulate(s.split('.'), lambda *x: '.'.join(x)))
```

Output:

```
['52', '52.13', '52.13.03', '52.13.03.014', '52.13.03.014.10']
```

*NB. You can also use `lambda a,b: a+'.'+b` as function in `accumulate`.*

Comment: @Is this truly the best way? If I had a list of thousands of 's' I would have to loop through them and then do this accumulate function

Comment: A million of these run in less than a second.  You are guilty of the crime of "premature optimization".  You are worrying about performance before you have any inkling there is a performance problem.

Comment: @mozway I already have the full account code. Is there a way to only get these values: ['52', '52.13', '52.13.03', '52.13.03.014',]

Comment: @Matthew `out[:-1]`? ;). Or better `list(accumulate(s.split('.')[:-1], lambda *x: '.'.join(x)))`

Comment: Awesome, I was using .pop beforehand.